# Git checkout between Ubuntu version

Tags: git, ubuntu, version-control, version, upgrade

Most of us sometimes have problems after upgrading the OS or programs or just after installing the package of programs, and some of  the have conflicts, and you spend a lot of time to resolve them.

Yesterday I have tried make `git init` in all main repositories. And after I upgraded to new version some of my programs. After I made commit of changes. So, now, I can just checkout between versions of my programs without any `virtual box` and so on. For example, it can be very useful to test you local project in different versions of PHP.

I tried upgrated `Ubuntu`(but I did it in my virtual box-because I did not now what can happened). And make`checkout between some versions`.  It  worked!

**Questions is:** can it have bad influence on my OS (I heard about some problems of hashing binary files, and it can bee a problem)?  Maybe this influence I cannot see, but they  are exist? Someone have some experience with this?

Comment: An alternative for your use case is using LVM. It allows you to do snapshots of a file system and roll back if the update went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bad influence? Only if:

- some of those files are in use by a process at the time of the checkout
- some of those files requires a special file protection mode (or suid bits), considering git only record [two protection modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621116/6309) (644 and 755)

Other than that, the size of those git repo can become an issue for some of the probram you might want to manage that way.
[If it is really big, a bug repo can be more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494211/6309).