# git, checkout is not removing the file

Tags: git

I don't get why by doing `git checkout filename` is not working.

Here are the steps. First, in the terminal:

[image]

Now `git status`:

[image]

I get a bunch of files that are modified. When I try with each of those files to `checkout` them I get this (I'll do an example with only 2 files):

[image]

Everything seems fine, but when I do a `git status` I can see those file again on the `modified` list:

[image]

So, I don't get. The only thing that came in mind is that another exe is reading and writing those files at every moment, but why not other files? I have a lot of files under `src/public`. This happen too if I restart (Windows) and the very first thing that I try is this (without opening IDE's or whatever) If I delete those files, I will remove the from the branch, I can't do that, I just want to remove them as `modified`. Any idea?

Edit: My last tries according to @VonC answer were:

```
274  git restore transpiler.sh
275  git config --global core.autocrlf false
276  git checkout transpiler.sh
277  git restore transpiler.sh
278  git checkout -- transpiler.sh
279  git checkout transpiler.sh
280  git status
```

still there the file...

Comment: Does `git checkout <filename> --` work?

Comment: What do you mean, with only 1 file? ah, with `--`, let me check

Comment: Yes, one after another and with the `--`

Comment: or just use `git restore <file1> <file2>` as suggested in the CLI

Comment: No, it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue persists with `git restore aFile` (which is easier than `git checkout -- aFile`, to avoid to specify to checkout that `aFile` is a file, not a branch), then check your configuration

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

I prefer making sure it is set to `false`, to avoid any automatic eol (end-of-line) conversion.
Then try `git restore` + `git status` again.

---

The [OP pmiranda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3541320/pmiranda) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264921/git-checkout-is-not-removing-the-file/61264979#comment108412055_61264979) to the other cause of automatic change: [`core.filemode`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode), that [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19621116/6309).

> Tells Git if the executable bit of files in the working tree is to be honored.

The remedy is:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

This avoids:

```
old mode 100755 
new mode 100644
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test. `git config core.autocrlf` returns `true`. Didn't work either. How can I set `core.autocrlf` false?

Comment: I put a comment at the end of my question, didn't work with `false` and `restore`

Comment: @pmiranda Do you have a .gitattributes in your repository? There could be directive changing the content of those files on checkout.

Comment: no, I don't that file, I have this ones: https://i.imgur.com/Xk48uGk.png ( I can't quote your name)

Comment: @pmiranda What does a `git diff` return for those two files?

Comment: `old mode 100755   new mode 100644` for both of them (actually for evey file from the modified list). So, it's a change of permission? what

Comment: Done, I got it with: `git config core.filemode false` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257613/3541320

Comment: @pmiranda This is indeed the second cause for automatic differences when cloning/checkout a repo. I have edited the answer accordingly, with links to past questions where I explain what that "filemode" is.