# Why does git create files with 664 permissions, not with 644?

Tags: git, file-permissions

[It is known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40979867/5006880) that git acknowledges only `644` or `755` file permissions. These values can be found in the `index` file, in relation to the corresponding files inside the working directory.

However, I found it out when git creates files in the working directory, whether in the course of cloning a repo or checking out onto a commit, it set the `664` (i.e. `rw-rw-r--`) bits to them in my case.

Why can this value be in use and not expected `644`? I know `umask` can influence permissions but it is only able to "take out" some bits, not to append additional ones.

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195019) in which OP says git uses the `644` value in his case. So does it all mean the issue is system-dependent and git doesn't try to force the `644` value at all?